# Load Particles.js into WordPress Website

Tags: javascript

I've followed the steps but my page isn't displaying the desired particle effects.

Hi everyone. I'm working locally on a WP site and decided to add the really cool-looking particles effect found at [particles.js](https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/) For some reason the particles simply won't load. I'm not even getting an error message :,( I've enqueued the necessary scripts and css files. Not sure what to do next.

I've attached my code below. Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you in

https://gist.github.com/Edwardtonnn/5fa8b3d2f845a699ea2cd73cc3293ed6.js

Comment: Can you embed the code directly in your question? You can put embed script tags in stack exchange posts, they're markdown not html. Is the problem that you don't see what you expect? Or have you confirmed that the script is not present in the html sent even if it's non-functional?

Comment: Also there is no copy of the `particles.js` library in your gist